# Embed jasper report in web application

Tags: web-applications, jasperserver

I have created some reports and deployed the same in jasper server. I am able to embed the reports in my web application by using  tag. The problem is the embed report displays the jasper server logo, menu bar and loggedin user information. But i don't want to show the same to end user. 
Can anybody help me how to achieve the above requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Append this onto your url:

```
&viewAsDashboardFrame=true
```

More generally, you need to force sitemesh to not decorate the page there are other ways to achieve this... but viewAsDashboardFrame is there specifically to help with that.